# Most useful Explorer shell extensions

Tags: windows, windows-shell

I'd like to know which are the most common (and useful) shell extensions you're using as developers. I bet the following are on the list, but I'd like to know which others you would add:

- Tortoise SVN
- Tortoise Hg
- Tortoise XXX (Git, CVS, whatever)

Any others worth mentioning?

Comment: Poll type questions should be community-wiki.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Can I move it or something?

Comment: community wiki means you want to give up ownership of your post so anyone can edit it, its not a synonym for "poll question". You don't have to wiki your question if you don't want to.

Answer (score 5):

[Open Command Window Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx).

Comment: The URL above is for the XP PowerToy for this, but it's also worth pointing out that Vista and 7 give you this option natively when you right-click on an Explorer folder while holding the Shift key (only in the main pane, though, not the Folders one).

Answer (score 4):

I love [FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/index.html) - Copy Full Path, Copy File Contents, Register, Move to Temp & lots more.

Answer (score 3):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not exclusive for development, but I really like [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Git Bash Here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (part of MSysGit, and very useful).